# Issue inferring type for generic

Tags: crystal-lang

I have a `c` library that I bind to, which has many structs that hold data of different types.

```
@[Link("foo")]
lib LibFoo

  struct IntStruct
    data : LibC::Int
  end

  struct DoubleStruct
    data : LibC::Double
  end

  fun get_int_struct(n : LibC::SizeT) : IntStruct*
  fun get_double_struct(n : LibC::SizeT) : DoubleStruct*

end
```

I have a generic class where I want the type `T` to be the type of one of those structs, based off of an input array.

```
class GenericClass(T)
    @ptr : Pointer(T)
    @obj : T

    def initialize(arr : Array)
        @ptr = infer_type(arr)
        @obj = @ptr.value
    end
end
```

Where `infer_type` looks like:

```
def infer_type(data : Array(Int32))
    return LibFoo.get_int_struct(data.size)
end

def infer_type(data : Array(Float64))
    return LibFoo.get_double_struct(data.size)
end
```

---

The code works fine when I explicitly set the type...

```
GenericClass(LibFoo::IntStruct).new [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

...but I would like to infer the type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe providing a custom generalized `new` method works for you?

```
struct A    
end

struct B    
end

class Generic(T)
  def self.new(items : Array(A)) forall A
    new(fetch_struct(items))
  end

  private def initialize(@struct : T)    
  end

  private def self.fetch_struct(items : Array(Int32))    
    A.new
  end

  private def self.fetch_struct(items : Array(Float64))
    B.new
  end
end

p Generic.new([1])
p Generic.new([1.0])
```

https://carc.in/#/r/7s6d

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you!  I especially like the `forall A`, that's a handy trick to use.